# HttpClient to download txt file having corrupt characters

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm trying to extract some txt files from a server, however the file character set is UTF-8.
My code is able to download the files, however it also produced some weird characters.

> Sydney�s Desalination Plant

If I download it directly using chrome, it displays correctly as :

> Sydney’s Desalination Plant

Below is my current code :

```
public String getURL(String url) throws Exception
{
    StringBuffer result=new StringBuffer();
    if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(url) && url.startsWith("http"))
    {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        client.getParams().setParameter("http.protocol.content-charset", "UTF-8");
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);

        // add request header
        //request.addHeader("User-Agent", "");
        //request.addHeader(Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8)
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

        System.out.println("Response Code : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200)
        {

            //System.out.println(response.getEntity().getContentType().getValue());
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(),"UTF-8"));
            //result=(EntityUtils.getContentCharSet(response.getEntity()));
            boolean flagIn = false;
            String sCurrentLine;
            while ((sCurrentLine = rd.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                //if(flagIn==false)
                //{
                //  sCurrentLine = removeUTF8BOM(sCurrentLine);
                //}

                if(flagIn)
                {
                    result.append("\n");
                }   
                 result.append(sCurrentLine);

                flagIn = true;
            }

        }
    }
    return result.toString();

}
```

and below is the method that tried to invoke :

```
System.out.println(former.getURL("http://photos.gcdis-india.com/png/bio/QSPNGC1002.txt"));
```

Any idea on which part I should fix? Do I need to provide any special http header? Or the Reader is the issue here?

Comment: That's not a normal quote.

Comment: The encoding is `windows-1252`. That's what it says in Firefox, and if I use that with your code it decodes fine. I don't know enough about browser defaults and HTTP to know why. It's not in any of the response headers.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Right click on the page and view info and see what charset it actually used.

Comment: Possibly ISO? Try not specifying what the character encoding is and just let java do the thinking in that respsect. And if you need it in a specific encoding for database entry you could always just convert it afterwards.

Comment: @ns47731, SotiriosDelimanolis It's not valid ISO-8859-1, I tried that and ended up with "Sydneys" (well it doesn't paste quite right in the editor, but it was one of those little boxes with four numbers in it).

Comment: ow. I thought it was UTF-8 all along. Thanks.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Check this out: http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/table-iso8859-1-vs-windows-1252.html -- I don't know how that helps us, but it's interesting, if you find these kinds of things interesting.

Comment: ow. I thought it was UTF-8 all along.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, here's the deal, as near as I can tell after trying your code with your URL.

First of all, don't assume you got UTF-8. Always use whatever character encoding is in the HTTP response header.

In your case, there's no actual encoding in the response header so you must fall back to some default. This is where things get iffy.

A number of sources recommend falling back to windows-1252, which does decode the apostrophe properly. The default for text/html is iso-8859-1 (http://www.w3.org/International/O-HTTP-charset) but iso-8859-1 does not decode that character properly.

I cannot find any hard reference that windows-1252 should be the default for text/plain. However, nearly every example of a text/plain request I could find defaults to that encoding. Therefore I can only conclude that it is, more often than not, a safe fallback.

So I would say:

1. Grab the character set from the response header (or from your entity).
2. If there isn't one and your content type is text/plain, default to windows-1252. If your content type is text/html default to iso-8859-1 (edit: or if you want to be even more robust, first decode the content as us-ascii, look for a character encoding in an html meta tag, then decode as that, otherwise iso-8859-1).
3. Specify that content type to the `InputStream`. Do not assume utf-8.

Everything I have found so far indicates that the above covers the majority of cases. I will continue looking around for definitive sources.

Comment: The character in question is Unicode 2019, which is one of the characters in the list of iso-8859-1 and windows-1252 differences (http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/table-iso8859-1-vs-windows-1252.html), and is "Right Single Quotation Mark". It has no representation in iso-8859-1.

Comment: Irritatingly, RFC 2046 section 4.1.2 (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2046#section-4.1.2) states in reference to text/plain: `The default character set, which must be assumed in the absence of a charset parameter, is US-ASCII.` and goes on to have a lengthy discussion about it. It goes way back to RFC 822 in ARPAnet days. I am unable to find an RFC that supersedes that with a new default, yet the fact remains that windows-1252 seems to be all over the place, and your document is definitely not us-ascii.